# requests.get() not returning proper text order when reading youtube HTML

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm using requests.get() to parse youtube HTML text. When I print the output after passing a link, one video is out of order.I am trying to play the videos in order using BeautifulSoup and the out of order video shows up before all other videos. Any advice or potential fixes would be helpful.

```
    true = requests.get(link +searched)
    page = true.text
    #print(page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    #print(soup)
    search_results = soup.findAll('a', attrs={'class': 'yt-uix-tile-link'})
    #print(search_results)
```

Additional code for more reference:

```
import pafy
import vlc
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
link="https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query="
youtube = "https://www.youtube.com"
word = "jid playlist"


def findlnks(searched):
    if '&list' not in searched:
        true = requests.get(link +searched)
        page = true.text
        #print(page)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
        #print(soup)
        search_results = soup.findAll('a', attrs={'class': 'yt-uix-tile-link'})
        #print(search_results)
    else:
        true = requests.get(searched)
        page = true.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
        #print(soup)
        search_results = soup.findAll('a', class_ ="spf-link playlist-video clearfix yt-uix-sessionlink spf-link")
        #print(search_results)
    return search_results

if 'mix' in word or 'playlist' in word:
    total_results = findlnks(word)
    i =0
    playlist_size=0
    #while i< 10:
        #print(total_results[i]['title'])
        #i+=1
    while 'list' not in (total_results[i])['href']:
        print(total_results[i]['href'])
        i = i + 1




    playlist_results=findlnks(youtube + ((total_results[i])['href']))

    while playlist_size<40:
        #print(youtube + (playlist_results[playlist_size])['href'])
        playlist_size = playlist_size +1

    while (playlist_results[playlist_size])['href'] !='\0':
        url = youtube + (playlist_results[playlist_size])['href']
        #print(url)
        video = pafy.new(url)
        best = video.getbest()
        playurl = best.url
        Instance = vlc.Instance()
        player = Instance.media_player_new()
        media = Instance.media_new(playurl)

        media.get_mrl()
        player.set_media(media)
        player.play()
        playing = set([1, 2, 3, 4])
        time.sleep(1)
        duration = player.get_length() / 1000
        mm, ss = divmod(duration, 60)

        while True:
            state = player.get_state()
            if state not in playing:
                break
            continue
        playlist_size = playlist_size +1
```

Comment: Can you share your `link+searched`?

Comment: And for your searched results, what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @HjSin I edited my post so it contains most of what I have so far. This should provide better context. This portion is to search for playlists in initial search results, then findlks is called again to get the url's of the videos inside the playlist. It works, they are just not in the order provided by youtube. You'll notice I also have a block which plays the videos retrieved from the playlist in VLC media player. I am having some trouble with playing videos once another is ended.

Answer (score 0):

Youtube uses ajax technology for the site. The requests library only works with the non-ajax site. Consider using the headless browser to get the html from youtube then extract the data.
You can you firefox in headless mode or phantomjs browser

I found this tutorial, it may help for you.
https://towardsdatascience.com/web-scraping-using-selenium-and-beautifulsoup-99195cd70a58

```
# Firefox session
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(videos_url)
# Try to increase the time if the page need more time to be fully loaded
driver.implicitly_wait(100)
```

Comment: How would I go about this. I just started with Python and I've never done Web Dev so these topics are quite new to me.

Comment: I found the tutorial about this. I hope it help ^^